# Print undeclared in this scope

Tags: c++

whenever I compile my file, the compiler would tell me that my print is not declared in this scope. The problem is I can't touch my main file since it belongs to my school. Does anyone know what to do? Thanks!

Compiler error message:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘void TestPush()’:
main.cpp:10:5: error: ‘Print’ was not declared in this scope
 Print(a);
 ^~~~~
```

In my .h file:

```
template <typename T>
class vector 
 {

private:
    T* v;
    int count;
    int capacity;
public:

vector(int capacity)
: v(new T[capacity]), count(0) {}

void Print(vector<T> s) {
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
    {
    std::cout<<v[i]<<" ";
    }
    std::cout<< "(size=" << size << "," << "capacity=" << capacity << ")";

}
}
```

In my main file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>              // atoi
#include "cs150_vector.h"

void TestPush(void)
{
std::cout << "\n********** TestPush **********\n";
cs150::vector<float> a;
std::cout << "Empty array:\n";
Print(a);

std::cout << "push_back 5 floats:\n";
for (float i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    a.push_back(i);
    Print(a);
}

std::cout << "pop_back until empty:\n";
while (!a.empty()) {
    a.pop_back();
    Print(a);
}
```

}

Comment: You accidentally declared `Print` as a member function of `vector`, so it would need to be invoked as `a.Print()`. Declare `Print` as a `friend` function and optionally separate its definition from its declaration.

Comment: Also, it is probably best if `Print` takes a `const vector<T>& s` argument, so you don't incur a copy and cannot accidentally modify `s`.